# How to isolate child form from the parent form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created an article form inside it there is another form to create one or more categories I want the behavior of the two submission buttons to be isolated.

_category_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with model: Category, url: categories_path do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.submit "Create Category" %>

<% end %>
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_with model: @article do |f| %>

  <!-- article fields -->

  <%= render 'category_form' %>

<% end %
```

When I submit the child form it submits the parent form.

Comment: If you want the 2 forms to be isolated than why do you place the one inside the other?

Comment: You may want to consult a question from 2008: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms] :)

Comment: Not sure if that's the best dupe target but the problem is not specific to Rails.